# In the entrance VS. at the entrance

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Is there any difference in meaning between these two prepositional phrases?

> - I am standing **at** the entrance
> - I am standing **in** the entrance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In the entrance" suggests actually within the doorway or entrance passage, or perhaps just inside the door or opening. The speaker might even be partly blocking the entrance. "at the entrance" more generally suggests "somewhere near the entrance", perhaps just outside it.

In many cases there will not be much practical difference of meaning.